# Accessing a database value in a models constructor in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, oop, model, laravel-5, php-7

I'm attempting to fetch, convert and save a value in a models' constructor in Laravel 5.2. The reason being that it's saved in the database as hex, and I need to convert it to binary pretty often, and would like to do it once and save the result in a class attribute. But I can't seem to be able to fetch the value from `$this` in the constructor.

Here's a excerpt of what I'm working with, guid is a field in my table.

```
class Person extends Model {
    private $bGuid = null;

    public function __construct(array $attributes = []) {
            parent::__construct($attributes);
            $this->ad = Adldap::getProvider('default');
            $this->bGuid = hex2bin($this->guid);
        }

    public function getName(){
        $query = $this->ad->search()->select('cn')->findBy('objectGUID', $this->bGuid);
        return $query['attributes']['cn'][0];
    }   
}
```

The `$this->ad` attribute executes as expected, but `$this->bGuid` does not. Some debugging shows that `$this->guid` when referenced in the constructor returns `null`. While if referenced in the `getName()` method directly works just fine.

My intermediate solution is creating a new function and just call `$this->getbGuid()`, thus making me a bit more satisfied with the DRY-ness, but it still has to convert it each time it is called.

I would appreciate it if anyone could tell me what's going wrong, so I could improve the code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to override another method from Model: `newFromBuilder()`.
This is the one that is executed once the data is retrieved from the DB, not the `__construct()` one:

```
class Person extends Model {
    private $bGuid = null;

    public function newFromBuilder($attributes = [], $connection = null)
    {
        $model = parent::newFromBuilder($attributes, $connection);

        $model->bGuid = hex2bin($model->guid);

        return $model;
    }
}
```

Note, that inside the overridden method you refer to the object as `$model` (instead of $this), and it has to return the `$model` object at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sorry to say that my project is long gone, but I appreciate the info. I don't have the source files handy, but it would definitely explain why putting it into the constructor didn't work. (And sorry for my delayed response)